# C# Xamarin error while installing xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nuget-package

When I try to install xamarin.forms version: 2.5.0.280555 I get this error:
"The "XamarinBuildAndroidResourceRestore" task could not be initialized with its input parameters" What can I do?

Comment: try building android application and resolve the errors

Comment: when I try to build I get the error: "This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.0.280555\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.props."

Comment: I'm struggling for hours!!!

Comment: Did you try nuget restore on solution level?

Comment: It works partly... thanks!

Comment: what is the other error you are getting ?

Comment: Something that works earlier with a View. this is the error: "Android.Views.InflateException" at this line: View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ProductInfo, container, false);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167874/discussion-between-a-vreeswijk-and-g-hakim).